# multiple arguments giving error web3

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereumjs, smart-contract-wallets

```
      .addMedicalReport(
        patientBio.id,
        patientBio.name,
        patientBio.birthDate,
        patientBio.phoneNumber,
        patientBio._address,
        patientBio.MedReportId,
        parseInt(patientMedicalData.weight),
        parseInt(patientMedicalData.height),
        patientMedicalData.bloodGroup,
        patientMedicalData.diseaseName,
        patientMedicalData.diseaseDescription,
        patientMedicalData.diseaseStartedOn
      ).send({ from: account })
      .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
        console.log('saved')
        // updateList(patientDataContract)
      })
```

solidity

```
function addMedicalReport(
    string memory patientId,
    string memory patientName, 
    string memory birthDate, 
    string memory phoneNumber, 
    string memory _address,
    string memory medReportId,
    uint weight,
    uint height,
    string memory bloodGroup,
    string memory diseaseName,
    string memory diseaseDescription,
    string memory diseaseStartedOn
    ) public {
      countSenders++;
    }
```

Error:

```
*react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at toUtf8Bytes (utf8.ts:210)
    at StringCoder.encode (string.ts:15)
    at array.ts:62
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (array.ts:54)
    at TupleCoder.encode (tuple.ts:23)
    at AbiCoder.encode (abi-coder.ts:106)
    at ABICoder.webpackHotUpdate../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.encodeParameters (index.js:121)
    at index.js:439
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (index.js:438)
    at Object._processExecuteArguments (index.js:701)
    at Object._executeMethod (index.js:720)
    at addUpdatePatientMedicalData (App.js:100)*
```

Comment: Hello. We need more of your javascript code. As it is clearly sayed in the error, something is indefined.

Answer (score 1):

The error was because of a typo mistake. I was passing an undefined argument which caused this error. Its not an error because of no. of arguments.